# How to open a website in chrome and automatically modified it

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, cmd, scrollto

Basically I want to run a command in cmd that will open the website at the position I set. Remove the class=navigation_box from it and have it scroll at the bottom. I have been able to move the website to the position i want but i haven't been successful in removing the objects I want and scroll it down. I tried with document.getelementbyID, .remove and scrollTo but nothing happened.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
--app="data:text/html,<html><body><script>window.moveTo(1080,0);window.resizeTo(970,525);window.location='https://www.iana.org/domains/reserved';window.scrollBy(0, 1000);</script></body></html>"
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you cannot do what you are trying to do if you don't control the page you're trying to land on. Because you will need the scollTo() script to exist on the landing page. Once you call window.location = '', the browser redirects. It's not going to execute your scrollTo() code.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use Chrome?

You might be able to use [Nightmare](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare) which is a headless browser that is easily scriptable from Node.js.

When you instantiate Nightmare you can instruct it to show the browser (otherwise it will be invisible) and enable dev tools:

```
const nightmare = Nightmare({
  openDevTools: {
    mode: 'detach'
  },
  show: true
});
```

Then point the browser at a web page:

```
nightmare.goto("http://www.google.com");
```

Note that you can point the browser at a local page in the file system:

```
nightmare.goto("file://path/to/some/file.html");
```

Nightmare has a `scrollTo` function that you can use to scroll to a particular part of the page. You can also inject JavaScript code into the page and you have that code call the scrollTo function within the browser or any other function you might want to call.

Nightmare has a handy 'screenshot' function that will allow you to capture a screenshot of the web page to an image file on your hard drive. It has many other features, so check out the [docs](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare).

Comment: yes I need to use Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox. I'm not permitted to install any software I like.